# Could someone turn these apache rewrites to nginx.. i just cant win it.

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

So i have spend many many many hours to fix this i just cant fix it.

The second one works somehow but when i go to /page i would like to grap css and js from root directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page
RewriteRule \/(.*)$ /$1 [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\-(.+)(min\.(js|css))$ $1.$3 [L]
```

This is what i have tryed

```
    location ~* (.+)\-(.+)(min\.(js|css))$ {
        try_files $uri $1.$3;
    }
    location /page\/(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri /$1;
    }
```

I got it working once but then i did vagrant provision and lost them.

Comment: instead of getting css and js through rewrite rule use `<base href="domainname/">` in your head section.

Comment: I have to use rewrite for that. Maybe in future i switch for that.

Comment: Your second location statement is missing `~` or `~*` between the directive name and the regular expression.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks but it didnt work ;/